# JBOSS and application properties

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss and would like to place my properties under JBOSS root directory. Say like /application/*.properties instead of the default conf folder /server/xxxx/conf/*.properties. Is this possible to do? What is the best approach to implement this if possible.

Comment: 4.x.x or 5.x.x right now I have 4.x.x, might migrate to 5.x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out this as we can add this to JBOSS clath path by adding the entry to the run.bat/run.sh

$JBOSS_HOME/application/